# UITableViewCell breaks layout when updating programmatic constraints

Tags: swift, uitableview

I know that Stackoverflow is not a help desk, but I just can't figure out what's wrong here:
I am building a Twitter clone. I am using a class with programmatic constraints as a tableview cell. Since the tweets sometimes contain images, sometimes rich links and sometime just text, I want the cell to dynamically change. Here is the problem: if the cell contains an image, the layout randomly breaks, like so:

[image: Account name and time is not correct.]

The debug navigator shows that there seems to be something wrong with the constraints of the image:

[image: the same constraints are added over and over again.]

Height and position of the top row including the name and date also seem to be ambiguous. If I scroll, tweets containing images look like this:

[image: The tweet contains an image, but it covers the whole text section.]

In the cell init, I add all the subviews and call the setConstraints function:

```
func setConstraints() {
    
    // User Image
    userImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    userImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: twentyOne).isActive = true
    userImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: distanceToContentViewLeading).isActive = true
    userImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: relativeUserImageHeightAndWidth).isActive = true
    userImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: relativeUserImageHeightAndWidth).isActive = true
    
    // User Name
    userNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    userNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: twentyOne).isActive = true
    userNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: relativeUserImageNameDistance).isActive = true
    
    // Confirmed User
    confirmedUserIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    confirmedUserIcon.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: twentyOne).isActive = true
    confirmedUserIcon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userNameLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true
    
    // Account Name
    twitterAccountNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    twitterAccountNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: twentyOne).isActive = true
    twitterAccountNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: confirmedUserIcon.trailingAnchor, constant: eleven).isActive = true
    twitterAccountNameLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    
    // Time Label
    timeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    timeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: twentyOne).isActive = true
    timeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: twitterAccountNameLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: eleven).isActive = true
    timeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: distanceToContentViewTrailing).isActive = true
    timeLabel.sizeToFit()
    
    // Bookmark Icon
    bookmarkIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bookmarkIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerIcon.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    bookmarkIcon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: likesCountLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: relativeDistanceBetweenCountAndNextIcon).isActive = true
    bookmarkIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone).isActive = true
    bookmarkIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone).isActive = true
    
    // Tweet Text
    tweetTextLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tweetTextLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: eleven).isActive = true
    tweetTextLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userNameLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tweetTextLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: distanceToContentViewTrailing).isActive = true
    
    // Invisible Border
    invisibleBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    invisibleBorder.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentViewWidth).isActive = true
    invisibleBorder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    invisibleBorder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
    
    // Answer Icon
    answerIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    answerIcon.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: invisibleBorder.bottomAnchor, constant: twentyOne).isActive = true
    answerIcon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userNameLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    answerIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone).isActive = true
    answerIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone).isActive = true
    
    // Answer Count
    answerCountLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    answerCountLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerIcon.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    answerCountLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerIcon.trailingAnchor, constant: eleven).isActive = true
    
    // Retweet Icon
    retweetIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    retweetIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerIcon.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    retweetIcon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerCountLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: relativeDistanceBetweenCountAndNextIcon).isActive = true
    retweetIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone).isActive = true
    retweetIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone).isActive = true
    
    // Retweet Count
    retweetCountLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    retweetCountLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerIcon.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    retweetCountLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: retweetIcon.trailingAnchor, constant: eleven).isActive = true
    
    // Likes Icon
    likesIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    likesIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerIcon.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    likesIcon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: retweetCountLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: relativeDistanceBetweenCountAndNextIcon).isActive = true
    likesIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone).isActive = true
    likesIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone).isActive = true
    
    // Likes Count
    likesCountLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    likesCountLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerIcon.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    likesCountLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: likesIcon.trailingAnchor, constant: eleven).isActive = true
    
    // Share Icon
    shareIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    shareIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerIcon.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    shareIcon.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trashIcon.leadingAnchor, constant: -eleven).isActive = true
    shareIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone - 3).isActive = true
    shareIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone - 3).isActive = true
    
    // Trash Icon
    trashIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    trashIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerIcon.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    trashIcon.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ellipsisIcon.leadingAnchor, constant: -eleven).isActive = true
    trashIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone - 3 ).isActive = true
    trashIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone - 3).isActive = true
    
    // Ellipsis Icon
    ellipsisIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    ellipsisIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerIcon.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    ellipsisIcon.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tweetTextLabel.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    ellipsisIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone - 3).isActive = true
    ellipsisIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconSizeiPhone - 3).isActive = true
    
    // Bottom Border
    bottomBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bottomBorder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerIcon.bottomAnchor, constant: twentyOne ).isActive = true
    bottomBorder.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: distanceToContentViewTrailing).isActive = true
    bottomBorder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: distanceToContentViewLeading).isActive = true
    bottomBorder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
    //bottomBorder.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75).isActive = true
    bottomBorder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -eleven).isActive = true
    
}
```

When dequeuing the reusable cell, I also call the setImageOrRichLinkConstraintsFunction to update the constraints:

```
func setImageOrRichLinkConstraints(postImage: UIImage?, link: String?, imageWidth: CGFloat, imageHeight: CGFloat) {
    
    // Tweet Image
    if postImage != nil {
        contentView.addSubview(tweetImageView)

        tweetImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        tweetImageTopAnchor = tweetImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tweetTextLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: twentyOne)
        tweetImageTopAnchor.isActive = true
        
        tweetImageTrailingAnchor = tweetImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tweetTextLabel.trailingAnchor)
        tweetImageTrailingAnchor.isActive = true
        
        tweetImageLeadingAnchor = tweetImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tweetTextLabel.leadingAnchor)
        tweetImageLeadingAnchor.isActive = true
        
        tweetImageHeightAchor = tweetImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (imageHeight))
        tweetImageHeightAchor.isActive = true
        tweetImageWidthAnchor = tweetImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (imageWidth))
        tweetImageWidthAnchor.isActive = true
        
        invisibleBoarderToImage = invisibleBorder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tweetImageView.bottomAnchor)
        invisibleBoarderToImage.isActive = true
        
    }
    
    else if link != nil{
        contentView.addSubview(linkPreview)
        linkPreview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        linkPreviewTopConstraint = linkPreview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tweetTextLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: twentyOne)
        linkPreviewTopConstraint.isActive = true
        
        linkPreviewTrainlingConstraint = linkPreview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tweetTextLabel.trailingAnchor)
        linkPreviewTrainlingConstraint.isActive = true
        
        linkPreviewHeightConstraint = linkPreview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentViewWidth - (distanceToContentViewLeading + relativeUserImageHeightAndWidth + relativeUserImageNameDistance + distanceToContentViewTrailing) * (16/9))
        linkPreviewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
        linkPreview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userNameLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        invisibleBorderToLinkPreview = invisibleBorder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkPreview.bottomAnchor)
        invisibleBorderToLinkPreview.isActive = true
    }
    else {
        invisibleBorderToTweetText = invisibleBorder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tweetTextLabel.bottomAnchor)
        invisibleBorderToTweetText.isActive = true
    }
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: One thing that is odd is the number of times constraints are duplicated in list of constraints you posted.  For example 'imageView.top = label.bottom + 8 @ 100' shows up at least three times.  I suspect that you need to implemement 'prepareCellForReuse' and make sure any constraints in the cell's view are removed before it is reused.

Comment: Using a series of UIStackViews would make your life so much easier. You can do this almost entirely with stack views.

Comment: @ScottThompson I agree. If a constraint is already active, setting the .isActive property to true sometimes clones the constraints (which I think is strange), but even with that fixed it still breaks.

Comment: @Rob I will give it a go but I also want to understand why this here doesn't work.